# How to format/change qmake build output

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, makefile, qmake

how can I format the make output (**!!by only changing the qmake project file!!**).
My compilation lines continue growing, and the one-line-warnings/errors almost disappear between them.

I am thinking of something like

```
$(CC) in.ext -o out.ext
```

thanks in regard

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In `qmake`, you can add a silent configuration option:

```
CONFIG += silent
```

(note: I think that's the command.  It's something similar to this.)

Which should suppress most of the output, and only print lines like "compiling a.o", along with your warnings and errors.  I believe this is similar to `make`'s `.SILENT.` directive (I think that's the one...)

You may want to be careful with this, however, because it suppresses a lot of information that error parsers like to use.  For example, if you are compiling with a `SUBDIRS` configuration, it won't print out when it changes to the different directories.

Answer (score 5):

There are different approaches.  And you can make them configurable.

- If you **add `@` sign** in front of the line within rule, the command itself won't be printed, but its output will.
- If you **add `-Werror` to your `CFLAGS`** variable (you do have one, don't you?  It's a common practice!), you definitely won't miss any warning--the build will stop after the first one.
- You can **redirect standard output of your command to `/dev/null`**, leaving only error stream (this is not for your particular case, because gcc usually doesn't yield output but may be helpful for other commands).

Unfortunately, for `qmake` only the second approach applies.  Add to your project file:

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS+=-Werror
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS+=-Werror
```

And the makefiles generated will use these flags when they invoke compiler, so the build will stop at every warning.

---

(this section will be moved to another question as soon an one appears).

For usual make you can use it all--you can make it all configurable!  Here's the example:

```
trace?=short

ifeq ($(trace),short)
  suppress_echo=@
  redirect_to_null=1>/dev/null

else ifeq ($(trace),full)
  suppress_echo=
  redirect_to_null=

else ifeq ($(trace),werror)
  CFLAGS+=-Werror

else
  $(error Incorrect trace type "$(trace)"!)
endif

# Thanks to Martin York for the source of this copy-pasted code
out.ext:  $(OBJ)
    @echo $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o out.ext $(redirect_to_null)
    $(suppress_echo)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o out.ext $(OBJ) $(redirect_to_null)
```

So, if you invoke `make` like this:

```
$ make trace=full
```

it will print everything.  If you invoke

```
$ make
```

the `short` value will be used by default (note the `?=` operator instead of usual `=`!) and the rules will expand to such version

```
out.ext: out.o
    @echo cc  -o out.ext 1>/dev/null
    @cc  -o out.ext out.o 1>/dev/null
```

what will give much as you need.

Such approach, with configuration, is used in production code.  For example, I saw it in Ubuntu's IcedTea makefiles.

Comment: Uh I want to make the magic unside and only inside qmake. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: +1: for -Werror. That's the best suggestion IMO and this _can_ be done in your project file.

Comment: thanks for your help guys, but -Werror does not provide what I need. (We cannot exit on warning, because we have deprecation warnings, which remain inside until the assigned worker changes the section)

Comment: If using the MSVC compiler, use `-WX` rather than `-Werror` to treat warnings as errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the printout with '@' and echo what you want to see:

Simple Example:

```
out.ext:  $(OBJ)
    @echo $(CC) -o out.ext
    @$(CC) -o out.ext $(OBJ) $(OTHER_FLAGS_ETC)
```

Comment: Uh I want to make the magic unside and only inside qmake. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: OP asked for qmake